# Modify ui-router state after creation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to change a `ui-router` state after it has been created?

I have setup my index state like this:

```
stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: defaults.ContentLayout,
                controller: 'contentLayoutController as ctrl'
            },
            'subNav@index': {},
            'pageContent@index': {
                template: '<div class="emptyContent"></div>'
            }
        }
    }
);
```

And I would like to add another view to the `views` collection on that state object. Is this possible? Here is what I have tried:

```
var indexState = stateProvider.state('index');  //this line fails
indexState.views.push(newViewObject);
```

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: In which place, are you trying to add ? config phase or controller method?

Comment: In the same phase as when I am adding my other states.

Comment: intercept the route change start, you can change the `toState` param there

Comment: @entre What? Thats not what I want to do. I want to add additional views

Comment: Are you looking like this http://plnkr.co/edit/2cTQmV0xzHOKYCMXcYQa ? you should prepare the object before registering..see commented line stateProvider.state('index', finalObj); in app.js?

Comment: Yes except `stateProvider.state('index', finalObj);` is being called before I try to append the new view. And its in a different function so it does not have access to `finalObj`.

Comment: Can you post your config phase code for better understanding?